# Measure time between functions in class?

Tags: php, mysql, class, oop

I am trying to understand OOP and made my own class to benchmark a MySQL DB

```
class Benchmark
{

    protected $sql, $db;
    public $result, $time;

    public function __construct($host, $user, $pass, $db, $result = array(), $time = null)
    {

        /* Vars */
        $this->db = $db;
        $this->result = $result;
        $this->time = $time;

        /*Start Timer */
        $this->time = microtime(true);

        /* Connect to DB */
        $this->sql = new \mysqli($host, $user, $pass);

        /* Measure Time and put result to array */
        $this->result['benchmark']['connect'] = $this->elapsedTime($this->time);


    }

    public function testMySQL()
    {

        /* Connect to DB */
        $this->sql->select_db($this->db);
        $this->result['benchmark']['selectDb'] = $this->elapsedTime($this->time);

        /* Fetch Version */
        $version = $this->sql->server_version;
        $this->result['benchmark']['version'] = $this->elapsedTime($this->time);
        $this->result['info']['version'] = $version;

        /* Benchmark */
        $this->sql->query('SELECT BENCHMARK(1000000,ENCODE("hello",RAND()));');
        $this->result['benchmark']['result'] = $this->elapsedTime($this->time);

        /* Close Connection */
        $this->sql->close();

        /* Total Time */
        $this->result['info']['total'] = $this->elapsedTime($this->time);

        $this->dump($this->result);

    }
}
```

However, the result is this:

```
Array
(
[benchmark] => Array
    (
        [connect] => 0.001
        [selectDb] => 0.001
        [version] => 0.001
        [result] => 10.181
    )

[info] => Array
    (
        [version] => 50713
        [total] => 10.181
    )

)
```

Why doesnt the time add up? Shouldn't `[total]` be `10.184` in this case?

The original idea is from here :https://github.com/odan/benchmark-php and that works. If I use the same data on that script, it adds up, where am I wrong? I guess it has something to do with my lack of OOP though...

**EDIT**

```
 public function elapsedTime($time)
 {
     return number_format(microtime(true) - $time, 3);
 }
```

Comment: Where is `elapsedTime` defiined?

Comment: Updated for clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are measuring the elapsed time since the timer is started, then each output is simply a point in that time period. The time it takes from initializing the timer until the result is obtained is not *in addition to* the time it takes to connect, select the db, and get the version, those are merely checkpoints along the way (which appear to be occurring virtually simultaneously, at least at the resolution of this timer). So, the total time *is* `10.181`, `.001` of which it took to perform the first three operations, not `.003`.

Comment: I see your point! I added the `elapsedTime` function. That shouldn't be a point, should it?

Comment: The function will still return "now - then", "then" being when the constructor was initialized, so effectively you're looking at the clock when these tasks are completed, but if the minute hand is still on 1 it does not mean three minutes have elapsed even if you look at it three times ;). This makes logical sense, however, as the three operations: connect, select, get version are all practically instantaneous compared to actually submitting a query and obtaining the result.

Comment: Great analogy with the clock. I totally understand the problem now! Thanks